# Angular places <style> after custom Style sheet <link>

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng

I am looking for an explanation concerning Angular style.

I am using Angular 10 with Prime-ng, I have added a custom style that should override a Prime-ng component, but when serving the App for test the style doesn't override it and it places  tags containing original style directly before <link ref="stylesheet" ../> that should override it.

[image: Angular places after custom Style sheet]

(1) contains css rules (injected on angular.json styles node) to be applied on p-progressbar ( i.e height: 10px; ).

(2) default style of Primeng component coming from Primeng library as I used this component on one of my app components:

```
<p-progressBar [value]="value"></p-progressBar>
```

A lot of thanks.

Comment: "*I have added a custom style that should override a Prime-ng component*" - Where did you define your custom style?

Answer (score 0):

If the PrimeNg component you want to update the styles isn't appearing in front of the body such as a Dialog, PopPup, Tooltip, etc. You can add the styles in the Angular component you are using the PrimeNg component. Otherwise, you need to add the styles in the styles.scss file, in order to these styles will be global.

If it doesn't work, add `!important` flag at the end of each style.